# Mapping a many-to-one relationship with a composite alternate key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities A and B with the following relationship

1. the foreign key in A consists of two columns (composite) that don't belong to the primary key of B (alternate key);
2. cardinality between A and B is [*] -- [0..1], that is, the foreign keys in A can be null and the many-to-one relationship is optional;
3. the relationship is unidirectional A --> B. I want to load B eagerly in A with a join.

How can I write hibernate mappings .hbm for A and B (hibernate 3, no annotations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a composite identifier property in the parent class (e.g. A):

```
    <properties name="ParentNaturalId">
        <property name="prop1" column="prop_1" />
        <property name="prop2" column="prop_2" />
    </properties>
```

And the Client references the Parent through this many-to-one association:

```
    <many-to-one name="parent" class="B" not-null="false" not-found="ignore" property-ref="ParentNaturalId" fetch="join">
        <column name="b_prop_1" />
        <column name="b_prop_2" />
    </many-to-one>
```

2. See the [**not-found="ignore"**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) many-to-one attribute:

> not-found (optional - defaults to exception): specifies how foreign
> keys that reference missing rows will be handled. ignore will treat a
> missing row as a null association.

3. See the [**fetch="join"**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) many-to-one attribute:

> fetch (optional - defaults to select): chooses between outer-join
> fetching or sequential select fetching.

Comment: Can you provide an authoritative reference for point 3? I'm confused with the default fetch types in hibernate and JPA.

Comment: The requirement 2 is addressed by "not-found" attribute, while 3 is how Hibernate manages *-to-one associations. All many-to-one are eagerly fetched by default. [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html) only defines EAGER and LAZY and each JPA implementation defines which mode to use for EAGER (JOIN or SELECT). [Check this document](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/) for some Hibernate fetch examples.

Comment: The link you provide indicates lazy with select as the default. Same here https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies That seem to contradict your previous comment. Can you clarify?